# Installing AMD drivers - dkpg error

Tags: drivers, server, dpkg

I am pretty noob on linux and this is probably a very simple error but I can't fix it.

I am trying to install AMD drivers for my card on Ubuntu server 14.04 (for a ethereum miner).

I followed this tutorial from AMD [www2.ati.com](http://www2.ati.com/relnotes/amd-catalyst-graphics-driver-installer-notes-for-linux-operating-systems.pdf)

What I did was the following:

I installed Ubuntu server and connected via ssh from my windows machine.

I checked my Ubuntu version, also checked that it was 64 bit.

I checked my graphics card version:

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA -> Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tonga PRO [Radeon R9 285/380] [1002:6939] (rev f1)
```

I go to the amd website to download the drivers. they should be under ​​​*Radeon™ R9 200, R7 200, HD 7000, HD 6000, and HD 5000 Series*, I go to the Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit link [support.amd.com](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu+x86+64).

I download the first one (don't know why there are so many) using wget

The problem comes when I try to unpackit (if it's the right word) using the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i fglrx_15.302-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb
```

I am given an error:

```
dpkg-deb: error: `fglrx_15.302-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb' is not a debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive fglrx_15.302-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb (--install):
subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
fglrx_15.302-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb
```

I am not able to fix this, please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Tt looks like the DEB is corrupt. It's much easier to just install `fglrx` using `apt-get` though: `sudo apt-get install fglrx`.

Comment: THANK YOU! it seems to be working, now my mining software detects the card, hopefully it will work as it does in windows. I am so happy and thankful this kind of sites exists, thank you very much again.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then :).

Comment: Most likely you ended up saving HTML as the .deb filename, or your browser did something wrong with compression when downloading it.

Answer (score 1):

The error you got tells me the DEB you downloaded is most likely corrupt. However, you don't need to go through the whole driver choosing thing from AMD; you can just install the driver using `apt-get`.

Run `sudo apt-get install fglrx`, reboot and you'll have the correct graphics driver.